# Telerik Kendo DropDownList with constant content in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a Telerik Kendo DropDownList that will have four items: "Patient List", "Benchmarking","Center Specific","ECMO Run". What is the simplest method to do that in razor (C#)? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("myDropDownList")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
          .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Patient List",
                  Value = "1"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Benchmarking",
                  Value = "2"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Center Specific",
                  Value = "3"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "ECMO Run",
                  Value = "4"
              }
          })
          .Value("1")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
    )
```

Above is just a sample code for create the drop down list using Kendo UI. 
Alternatively, you can simply use plain HTML `<select>` tag to create a drop down list.

```
<select id="size" style="width: 100%;">
   <option value=1>Patient List</option>
   <option value=2>Benchmarking</option>
   <option value=3>Center Specific</option>
   <option value=4>ECMO Run</option>
</select>
```

Also please check out following link for more details.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/index

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention. The code seems very logical, but when I copied it on my page, I only saw a text box with value 1.I have tried the code in Mozilla and Chrome. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @alenan2013 try the steps from this link, and see if your configurations are all correct. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5#add-telerik-ui-for-aspnet-mvc

Comment: If you are using the provided code "as-is", you may be getting a javascript error due to the "change" handler not being defined, which will prevent the dropdownlist from being fully created.  You may need to either remove the .Events(e => e.Change("change")) configuration or provide the javascript code for the "change" function as shown in the linked telerik demo page.

Comment: Thank you both :) the problem was really in the "change" event. Without event everything works fine. Thank you again.